# Tomcat response time dependency on the user count

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, performance-testing, cpu-usage

I tested how much time it takes to receive the responses for many concurrent ajax requests sent from a Chrome browser to a Tomcat on a Linux VM. It seems that the response time for a request is increasing as the number of concurrents requests is increasing. In contrast, the CPU time used by Java to process a request on the server is even slightly decreasing as the number of concurrent requests is increasing.

[image]

The Java uses the prosessor only immediately on the receipt of all the requests, afterwards as the responses are being sent the processor is not used by Java.[image]

Would you have how I could decrease the response time for concurrent requests? What else except Java could be important for sending out the Tomcat responses from a Linux machine.

Thank you

Comment: You probably need to tune the connector, see https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/http.html

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Web Applications Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/), [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.